# Aggrid-how to add data bindings masterDetailComponent

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am implementing Aggrid master details component, and its working fine, now i want to display chart in the place details grid, which is working fine too. but the problem is **I want to have binding to from Gridmaster to detailsPanel component to change the chartType dynamically.**

I have dropdown in each row with chartLinks in the option(pie, bar, line, etc). On clikc of those link it should update the detailsComponent chartType property.

Something like below:

[image]

Comment: I suppose you need to use `fullwidth` row in details grid, and via additional renderer handle your chart stuff.
doc:https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-full-width-rows/

Comment: i want to update the chartType from My parent row select dropdown link, i am using the same fullWidthrRnderer, but its not possible to trigger an event to child(chartcomponent).

Comment: why? you can use this sample: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#angular-cell-render-components as an example of event-based cooperation between parent\child

Comment: thanks I am able to use renderer to share the data now

Comment: so you can mark the question as solved